# how to build lots of apk by Gradle, The only difference is a assets file

Tags: android, build.gradle

I want to use Gradle build Android.
There are almost 100 apk for all appStores.The only difference is  a assets/config.properties file.

The Ant Script:

```
<target name="makechannelidapk">
    <propertyregex property="channel_id" input="${line_content}" regexp="(.*)," select="\1"/>
    <delete file="${asset-dir}/config.properties" />
    <echo file="${asset-dir}/config.properties"CHANNEL_ID=${channel_id}</echo>

    <antcall target="finalmake" >
        <param name="id" value="${client_source}"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question.

Comment: programming：code,qa,compile,ide,build,deploy, etc

Comment: There are many Android developer support sites on the Internet, offering help in many languages. I have some sites listed at http://www.andglobe.com. You may have better luck with a site that is in a language that is more comfortable for you. Otherwise, if you want help here, you will need to actually **ask a question**.

Answer (score 0):

**use meta-data**

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:value="${CHANNEL_VALUE}" android:name="CHANNEL"/>
```

build.gradle

```
    android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        // default CHANNEL_VALUE
        manifestPlaceholders = [CHANNEL_VALUE: "default"]
    }
    productFlavors {
        fir{}
        wandoujia{}
        qihu360{}
        baidu{}
        xiaomi{}
        uc{}
        productFlavors.all{
            flavor->flavor.manifestPlaceholders = [CHANNEL_VALUE: name]
        }
    }
}
```

**get meta-data**

```
try {
    ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
    String myApiKey = bundle.getString("CHANNEL");
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load meta-data, NameNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load meta-data, NullPointer: " + e.getMessage());         
}
```